# Copying files into new destination folder while maintaining folder structure

Tags: powershell, tree, directory

I am using the PowerShell `Copy-Item` cmdlet to try and copy a directory structure.  This structure contains a number of sub-folders which I need to maintain.  I am using the command:

```
Copy-Item <<src folder>> <<dest folder>> -Recurse
```

If the I make sure the destination folder exists first, then all is well.  If, however, it does not exist, then PowerShell will create it, but the folder structure that is copied misses out the first level.  e.g, if my source folder structure is:

```
D:\tmp\copytest
└─ 1
   ├─ 1.1
   │  └─ 1.1.txt
   └─ 1.txt
```

and I use the command

```
Copy-Item "D:\tmp\copytest\*" "D:\tmp\copied" -Recurse
```

then the destination folder looks like this if I did not create the 'copied' folder in advance:

```
D:\tmp\copied
├─ 1.1
│  └─ 1.1.txt
└─ 1.txt
```

i.e. there is no '1' subfolder.

Whilst ensuring the destination folder exists is no big deal, I'm interested in trying to understand what's going on here.

Comment: Try [Robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy), Microsoft's robust tool for copying files and directories.

Comment: @vonPryz sure I could, but I'd rather use native powershell, and I'd like to understand why I'm seeing this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to recreate your issue.

```
New-Item -Path C:\test\1 -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
New-Item -Path C:\test\1\1.txt -ItemType File | Out-Null
New-Item -Path C:\test\1\1.1 -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
New-Item -Path C:\test\1\1.1\1.1.txt -ItemType File | Out-Null
Copy-Item -Path "C:\test\*" -Destination "C:\temp" -Recurse
Get-ChildItem C:\temp -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

Output:

```
C:\temp\1
C:\temp\1\1.1
C:\temp\1\1.txt
C:\temp\1\1.1\1.1.txt
```

Comment: Did C:\temp exist before you did the Copy-Item?  If it did, then I get the same behaviour as you - all is well.  If not, that's when it doesn't work properly for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have Copy-Item recursing properly,
Source and Destination should be balanced.

On my empty RamDisk, this script:

```
$Drive = "A:"
New-Item -Path "$Drive\tmp\copytest\1\1.1"         -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
New-Item -Path "$Drive\tmp\copytest\1\1.txt"       -ItemType File      | Out-Null
New-Item -Path "$Drive\tmp\copytest\1\1.1\1.1.txt" -ItemType File      | Out-Null

Tree /F $Drive

Copy-Item -Path "$Drive\tmp\copytest\" `
   -Destination "$Drive\tmp\copied\" -Recurse

Tree /F $Drive
```

has this output:

```
Auflistung der Ordnerpfade für Volume RamDisk
A:\
└───tmp
    └───copytest
        └───1
            │   1.txt
            │
            └───1.1
                    1.1.txt

Auflistung der Ordnerpfade für Volume RamDisk
A:\
└───tmp
    ├───copied
    │   └───1
    │       │   1.txt
    │       │
    │       └───1.1
    │               1.1.txt
    │
    └───copytest
        └───1
            │   1.txt
            │
            └───1.1
                    1.1.txt
```

Comment: not sure what you mean by 'balanced'.  If you mean that the folder you are specifying as the destination needs to exist then, yes, that makes sure the recursing happens properly.  What I don't understand is why having powershell create that folder means the recursion seemingly goes awry..
  
One thing I did notice from your post is that if I miss out the '*' on the end of the source path definition then it works as I would expect.  i.e.  

    Copy-Item "C:\test\" "C:\copiedto" -Recurse

Rather than

    Copy-Item "C:\test\*" "C:\copiedto" -Recurse  
  
Which is interesting...

Comment: Sorry about the formatting in that reply - can't seem to get indenting or line breaks :-(

Comment: IMO The asterisk in combination with the `-Recurse` parameter **IS** the issue. There are some related Q&A here on [SO].

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of Copy-Item differs depending on whether the directory path specified by the -Destination parameter exists or not.

```bsh
Copy-Item -Path "D:\tmp\copytest\1" -Destination "D:\tmp\copied" -Recurse
```

If the "copied" directory does not exist, the directory "1" is copied with the name "copied". On the other hand, if the "copied" directory exists, the directory "1" will be copied directly under the "copied" directory.

If you copy the directory, you should check in advance whether the destination directory exists. The easy way is below.

```bsh
Copy-Item -Path "D:\tmp\copytest\*" -Destination (mkdir "D:\tmp\copied" -Force) -Recurse
```